# Disable Email notification to Group Members from SharePoint when Granting Permission

Tags: sharepoint-online

We are using SharePoint online. We have a Group in which many users are added. If I try to give permission on a list by Sharing the list to that group (Example see image below) an email goes out to all the users in that group. We don't want these emails to be sent out. I know that there is a check box in the "Shared With" dialog (see image below) that can turn off the notification.

However a perfect solution would be to disable any notification when permission is changed on a list or Group because sometime admin forgets to uncheck the notification checkbox. Is there a setting which can be turned on or off to achieve this?

[image]

Thanks
Dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SharePoint on premise, you can disable “send an email invitation” when providing user permission.

Disable “send an email invitation” when providing user permission:

http://sharepointsharks.blog/disable-send-an-email-invitation-when-providing-user-permission/

But in SharePoint online, there is no method to disable “send an email invitation” when providing user permission. The only method is to uncheck “send an email invitation” when providing user permission.

I would recommend you submit a feedback about this issue via the below link for your convenience, thanks.

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/

It is a place for customers provide feedback about Microsoft SharePoint products. What’s more, if a feedback is high voted there by other customers, it will be promising that Microsoft Product Team will take it into consideration when designing the next version in the future.